# Having error while trying to run gulp on laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am trying to configure a Laravel project I have configured node and bower with no problem but after sudo npm install gulp. when I run gulp I get this error

> module.js:341
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>       at Object. (/home/gulpfile.js:1:76)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

Internet search solutions suggested to change the gulp.js file first line to

> var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

but it's already there.

Comment: Did you run npm install inside your project folder. Think you need to pull in elixir?

Comment: What do you see when you run 'npm ls | grep elixir' ?

Comment: on root nothing happens and in the project directory im getting errors

Comment: Can you make sure this is in your packages.json file : "laravel-elixir": "*",

Comment: yea its already there 
`"dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "*",
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109379/discussion-between-anderscc-and-user2431114).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend removing everything from inside your node_modules folder and running `npm install` again. By the sounds of it, something hasn't been pulled in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

please read the instructor of using gulp 
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

need to install globally and locally to use in project if you follow this I think your problem will solve

Comment: did that didnt work. is there any work around for installing elixir

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install` to install all the dependencies before you can start using elixir and gulp

Answer (score 0):

Remove All data inside node_modules folder and follow the below steps:

**npm install --global gulp**

Then run:

**npm install**

All done !! Run:

gulp